# Fraction formatting as halves or one third or quarters in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, formatting, fractions

I have some double-precision values in a column in PostgreSQL as following:

```
**amount**
*11.33
11.75
12.2
13.9
16.3
.....*
```

I want to round these values to their nearest quarter value at the decimal place. That is:

```
11.333569 -> 11.50
11.7555698 -> 11.75
12.236558 -> 12.25
13.925669 -> 13.75
16.101235 -> 16.25
```

I saw this kind of feature in MS Excel. It can be found at:
[image: ]]

How can I do the same in PostgreSQL? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use arithmetic:

```
select cast(round(x * 4) / 4.0 as decimal(10, 2))
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=87dbff0dd11fce0f9e63fc0bd8b83905) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Many thanks. This is now working for halves and quarters. But can not figure out for three-quarters.

Comment: @ShamsurRahimHemel . . . It works for 0.75 as well.